# Alguien tiene un ejemplo de la función Exp en flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy buscando un ejemplo de exp o exponencial o elevar x numero pero no eh podido captar lo que quiere decir esto que esta en la pagina de flutter:

```
double exp (
num x
)
```

Comment: buscas algo así? https://flutter-examples.com/dart-calculate-find-cube/#:~:text=In%20Flutter%20the%20'dart%3Amath,the%20mathematical%20exponent%20related%20calculations.

Comment: ¿Buscar como elevar `x` al exponente `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta no es clara, pero puedo inferir que lo que deseas hacer elevar un numero a un exponente.

Si eso es lo que deseas, la función correcta en dart es `pow` puedes usarla de esta forma:

```
resultado = pow(3, 3);
```

Si haces un print de resultado te dara como salida un 27.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias me ayudo bastante! Me fue muy útil con eso pude sacar la raíz cuadrada y elevar una potencia.

```
 else if(buttonText == "√"){
    equationFontSize = 48.0;
    resultFontSize = 38.0;
    double rz= double.parse(equation);
    double r=pow( rz , 1/2);
    result=r.toStringAsFixed(6);
    }

  else if(buttonText == "χ²"){
    equationFontSize = 48.0;
    resultFontSize = 38.0;
    double rz= double.parse(equation);
    double r=pow( rz , 2);
    result=r.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
```